# heroku puma web dyno dedicated for an exclusive rails api endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, heroku, puma

I have a rails app with two main endpoints:

```
POST /api/verifications
GET /api/summarize
```

Particularly /api/verifications receive json data in high speed sequential way, but for every reception, a complex duplicate searching logic must be done. This searching logic some times must allow duplicated data and some times must not allow duplicated data (due to logic conditions that implies querying multiple postgres tables plus table in which incomming data is stored). The problem occur when arrive two sequential requests with differences of millisecond containing duplicated data and first request must be allowed but second doesn't. I guess that a puma thread is attending first request and start the complex searching logic for duplication, and just immediately a second thread starts the same with second request. So they don't find each other and they allow both incoming data and then it is stored on target table (saving both!!)

The web dyno is behind an ngninx that is acting as a reverse proxy.

My idea of solution (but i'm not sure) is to define just 1 worker with just 1 thread looking for a way of enqueing incoming data for gaining chance of: receiving -> searching -> saving if duplicate logic allow it -> receiving (on next incomming request with data) ... etc

But the other endpoint (/api/summarize) is highly consumed so definitely I need another thread for attending it.

So my questions would be, will my proposed solution of using 1 worker 1 thread solve the problem? If so, how another thread or another puma worker could be dedicated to **/api/summarize**. Is it possible to dedicate a webdyno for an exclusive endpoint? or is it possible for just one webdyno, to instantiate two puma worker each one for a specific endpoint (one for POST /api/verifications and another one just for GET /api/summarize)

Thankyou very much for your advice.

Greetings.

Comment: Removing concurrency will remove all race conditions... but it will also castrate application performance and limit any possibility to scale the app. Your only solution is to re-think the design at it's core.

Comment: Thank you @Myst, you confirm my suspicions. In my situation it's a very difficult decision. I was thinking to dedicate actual heroku app just to dedicate onto my 'not probably concurrent endpoint', and create a new replica heroku (sharing database) app for everything else, due to it's possible that 'everything else' can redirect to the new instance. What do you think about it ?